# Man and LANG issue

Tags: language, man, i18n

My LANG=ru_RU.cp1251 so if man page was translated I get garbage
in output.

Problem lies out of 'cp1251' because /usr/share/man/ru store
man pages in different encoding:

```
  /usr/share/man/ru/man1/mc.1.gz is UTF-8
  /usr/share/man/ru/man1/mplayer.1.gz is koi8-r
```

Also man does not support page recoding on fly:

```
  $ ls -ld /usr/share/man/ru*
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 user root 0 июн 10  2010 /usr/share/man/ru
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 user root 0 окт 13 10:10 /usr/share/man/ru.KOI8-R
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 user root 0 окт 13 10:10 /usr/share/man/ru.UTF-8

  $ test -f /usr/share/man/ru.KOI8-R/ex.1.gz && OK
OK

  $ LANG=ru_RU.cp1251 man ex
... EN output ...
  $ LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 man ex
... EN output ...

  $ LANG=ru.UTF-8-8 man ex
... !!RU output!! ...
```

so man can not strip '_RU' from 'ru_RU'!

I would like to see only EN man pages. According to 'man 1 man' I
need set 'LANG=C', but I like 'LANG=ru_RU.cp1251'!

I try add:

```
  LANG C
```

to /etc/man.conf, but got warning:

```
  Unrecognized line in config file (ignored)
  LANG C
```

In bash I can define alias:

```
  $ alias man='LANG=C man'
```

But how about Emacs M-x man? I need write a wrapper and set

```
  (setq manual-program "LANG=C man")
```

In order to fix page lang for MC  and bash I put

```
  alias man='LANG=C man'
```

to ~/.bashrc

Seems I cover all my use cases but I have a questions:

- Is it possible set LANG setting for man without setting LANG=C to
  all other apps (like Emacs, MC)? I would like see option in
  'man.conf'
- Is it right provide /usr/share/man/ru/ with files with different
  encoding? I think packages must fixed to 'ru.UTF-8', ru.KOI8-R
  path.